# Show/Hide not working properly?

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of HTML:

```
        <div class="clearfix wanted_item">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="float_right"><img src="images/pin.png"></div>
                <div class="float_right">
                    <h3>a</h3>
                    <div>abcd</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="float_right more_details" style="display: block;">
                                    <ul>
                    <li>some list</li>                  </ul>
                <div class="application_link">                      
                    <a class="orange_button" href="volunteer.php?volunteer_type=1"><span>apply</span></a>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="float_left clearfix more_details_link" href="javascript:void(0);">Show details</a>
        </div>
```

And I have this jQuery code:

```
$(".less_details_link").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".more_details").slideUp(500);
    $(this).text("Show details");
    $(this).removeClass('less_details_link');
    $(this).addClass('more_details_link');
});
$(".more_details_link").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".more_details").slideDown(500);
    $(this).text("Hide details");
    $(this).removeClass('more_details_link');
    $(this).addClass('less_details_link');
});
```

For some reason when I click the 'show' link it works properly, I can also see that it changes the class to `less_details_link` but the second `click()` function fails to work without any output to the console log. When I click the 'Hide details' link it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you put this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/PjBYJ/)***

That is because when you add a class to an element, it does not bring the event handler with it unless you use on ([jQuery API: on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) for the event handler

```
$("body").on("click",".less_details_link",function() {
 $(this).parent().children(".more_details").slideUp(500);
 $(this).text("Show details");
 $(this).removeClass('less_details_link');
 $(this).addClass('more_details_link');
});
$("body").on("click",".more_details_link",function() {
 $(this).parent().children(".more_details").slideDown(500);
 $(this).text("Hide details");
 $(this).removeClass('more_details_link');
 $(this).addClass('less_details_link');
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Just curious why doesn't Kacey's solution work and yours does?

Comment: @hoverhand - Kacey did not use event delegation. When used in that form, `on` will merely attach the click event similar to your original approach. When `on` is used in this form, it will delegate the event out which is what allows future elements to have that event handler. [jQuery API: on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @hoverhand he's correct. I replied so fast that I didn't think about that.

Comment: my god man, if ur gonna have all this unnecessary code to bind separate click events, at least chain all the stuff. done on `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is way more complex than it needs to be. Its one link, just give it an extra class to denote if expanded or not, then do a simple if function to determine if active or not.

Thank you @Kacey for the `.slideToggle()` and `.toggleClass()` recommendation, even simpler.

```
$(".more_details_link").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this
        .toggleClass('active')
        .prev()
        .stop()
        .slideToggle(500);

    $this.hasClass('active') ? $this.text("Show details") : $this.text("Hide details");
});
```

Edited to use ternary if function for text.

Comment: How about `.toggleSlide()` and `.toggleClass()`? That would make it even less complex.

Comment: good call, there was so much to clean up i didnt think about it

Comment: so much for code efficiency, once it works no once cares about speed. geez.

Answer (score -1):

When your jQuery loads, there's no `.less_details_link` available, so it can't hook the `.click()` function to it. What you want to do is set your functions up like so:

```
$(".less_details_link").on("click", function() { ... }
$(".more_details_link").on("click", function() { ... }
```